# How to know if Serilog.LoggerConfiguration.Write was successful?

Tags: c#, serilog, datadog

My application needs to log exceptions to DataDog using `Serilog.LoggerConfiguration` and `DatadogConfiguration`. I've got this working well:

```
var config = new DatadogConfiguration(
      url: "DATA_DOG_URL",
      port: PORT,
      useSSL: true,
      useTCP: true);

using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration().
                        WriteTo.
                        DatadogLogs
                        (
                            "MY_API_KEY",
                            service: "MY_SERVICE_NAME",
                            configuration: config,
                        ).
                       CreateLogger())
{
    //write the message
    log.Write(LogEventLevel.Error, "My message...");
}
```

The wrinkle is that my application often runs offline, when a write to DataDog clearly can't succeed. But the `Write` method by design [doesn't throw exceptions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability) nor return any value confirming success. In my testing, it looks like calling `Write` when offline appears to succeed but in fact discards the message.

What I want to do is log messages to a file, whether online or off, and then forward them to DataDog when online. But if I do the online detection myself, there could be a race situation like

```
if(online)
   do the logging
```

but the connection is lost after the detection but before the logging succeeds.

I can't use the DataDog Agent, because this software has to be installed on end user machines and configuring something like that would create major support issues, and may not be allowed by many user environments.

So I'm looking for a way to reliably write the log entry and know that it worked, so I can make sure not to lose messages.

Comment: If you need guaranteed writing is this really logging or rather auditing?

Comment: According the docu Serilog has Auditing features. I don't know where DataDog attaches but can you simply replace WriteTo with AuditTo?

Comment: @Ralf: There is no `AuditTo` method, and [according to DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/knowledge-center/audit-logging/#audit-logs-vs-regular-system-logs), the difference between logging and auditing doesn't seem to be about transactionality, but "The difference between audit logs and regular system logs (e.g., error logs, operational logs, etc.) is the information they contain, their purpose, and their immutability."

Comment: Maybe not from the DataDog view. But auditing means guarantees. Something can happen only if its audited. If serilogs auditing isn't usable here you could try adding an exception handler (and presumably setting the batchsize to one) when setting up the Datadog sink. Writing logs is an async process in most cases it isn't written directly presumably also for the DataDog sink so expect the exceptionhandler to fire later (i assume  that behavior not know that behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I never could get this working, so I dropped Serilog and went to the DataDog [REST API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/) so I could send my own messages directly and have granular control over the success or failure of the send.